# How can this advanced function type be achieved?

Tags: typescript, types

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGgPAFShAHsCA7AJgZyj4AJwEsMBzAPigF4oADLAe30YFsJgALUsqTiQtADuxLlAAkAbwQBfOgCh5AY0YYCUAGaNmtOCrXAoAQWRpMufER4AaKACFT6bHnhGKFABTAArmAA2EABcUADaAIbBRrYARsF2ALoAlDRUPv4Q8lqMHiEA5GG5tgzMOGwc3OR8AsKinFBhdEmKAPTNUAASjEJQTFAAklBCJOia2gBM+N5KdVxhhqL1SkoQYMB4YRj1hIRhIFAeAG5hJGHRAVBpAQB0N8lC-ILIYdNQ7KzRAnxheKCQUKQaaoYZajQj-Nb4CD6LDIALsDCGaLfCAw1TgvAaYiEAgAfky4xy8igxNC+UK9F6pXYXB4VUeIjEDXi1iJJLy0XJxRY1IqvAeNTE0UaLJJpKUnMpZRplX5g1qUCUwtZxNaUBuV3kSSAA)

```
type X<T extends string> = `do something here with ${T}`

const foo = <const A extends string, B extends X<A>>(tuple: [a: A, b: B]) => tuple
foo(['a', `do something here with a`])

// How do I write foo2 such that it accepts an array (variable tuple...) where each member has type inference for its second element based on its first?
foo2([
    ['a', `do something here with a`],
    ['b', `do something here with b`],
    ['c', `do something here with c`],
    // ...
])
```

An array of tuples where the second element type depends on the first element type. Each tuple's type within the array should not affect types of other tuples in the array.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WvkKYw) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I found one counter example that [does not work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGgPAFShAHsCA7AJgZyj4AJwEsMBzAPigF4oADLAe30YFsJgALUsqTiQtADuxLlAAkAbwQBfOgCh5WCAGMANgENBUAGYBXDCuDFGGXY0YAmOCtMEoSVOmx5BGphjUh8RHgG0AXQoACmA9MDUIHAAuKDcPLyg-ADpUySSASShSKABrCBBGHQcA6PkoCqSNWIQ-DICAGigAI1j4WvqKAPkZAIBKWIA3RmIsAG5FHQtLYL9KqHLKvwByAC9lpoAiJhZ2Lh4+AWFRTigUTYCoAHorqDgAWnv8TkY9NSwW6AFCRkImlCgAEJqLRVvN5P0gA). Can you fix that?

Comment: Ah, maybe [this version](https://tsplay.dev/W4bPON) or [this version](https://tsplay.dev/Nav22m) then?

Comment: The former version works! Impressive! A lot in here for me to learn. What is the advantage of the latter version? I see its syntax difference, but to what effect?

Comment: They are both ways of achieving *noninferential type parameter usage* as requested in [ms/TS#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829).  Not sure if one is more "advantageous" than another.  Anyway I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make `foo2()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `T`, the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of the first ("`a`") elements of the inputs.  So if you call

```
foo2([
    ['a', `do something here with a`],
    ['b', `do something here with b`],
    ['c', `do something here with c`],
]);
```

then `T` should be the tuple type `["a", "b", "c"]`.  Here's the first attempt at a solution:

```
declare function foo2<T extends readonly string[]>(
    tuples: readonly [...{ [I in keyof T]:
        [a: T[I], b: X<T[I]>]
    }]): void;
```

The `tuples` input is essentially of the [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) `{[I in keyof T]: [a: T[I], b: X<T[I]>]`, meaning that for each element of `T` at index `I`, the value `T[I]` will be transformed into `[a: T[I], b: X<T[I]>]`.  I've got that type wrapped in a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) `readonly [...⋯]` in order to give the compiler a hint that we want `T` to be inferred as a tuple and not an unordered array type.

So if you pass in `tuples` as `[["x", X<"x">], ["y", X<"y">]]`, then `T` should be inferred as `["x", "y"]`.

This mostly works:

```
foo2([
    ['a', `do something here with a`], // okay
    ['b', `do something here with b`], // okay
    ['c', `do something here with c`], // okay
    // ...
    ['x', "do something here with w"], // no error?!
    ['y', "do nothing"], // error
    ['z', "do something here with z"] // okay
])
// foo2<["a", "b", "c", "x" | "w", "y", "z"]>(⋯)
```

Except that for  `['x', "do something here with w"]`, the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `"x" | "w"` was inferred for the corresponding element of `T`.  This is reasonable behavior, but not what you want.  Indeed, you want `T[I]` to be inferred only from the first ("`a`") elements of the inputs, not from the second ("`b`") elements.  That means you want the second elements to use `T[I]` only for *checking*, not for *inferring*.

There's a longstanding open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) to support *non-inferential type parameter usages*.  The idea is that there'd be a `NoInfer<T>` utility type so that one could write

```
declare function foo2<T extends readonly string[]>(
  tuples: readonly [...{ [I in keyof T]:
    [a: T[I], b: X<NoInfer<T[I]>>]
}]): void;
```

and the compiler would understand that it should not use that `b` element of the tuple to infer `T[I]`.  There is currently (as of TS5.0) no direct support for this, but there are various techniques available which work.  One is mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-504042546), where you define `NoInfer<T>` as a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) in order to defer its evaluation:

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends unknown ? 0 : never]
```

With that definition of `NoInfer<T>`, you get the behavior you want:

```
foo2([
    ['a', `do something here with a`], // okay
    ['b', `do something here with b`], // okay
    ['c', `do something here with c`], // okay
    // ...
    ['x', "do something here with w"], // error!
    ['y', "do nothing"], // error! 
    ['z', "do something here with z"] // okay
])
```

Another approach is described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-288902999), where you add an additional type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the first one because constraints don't act as inference sites (see [microsoft/TypeScript#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234):

```
declare function foo2<T extends readonly string[], U extends T>(
    tuples: readonly [...{ [I in keyof T]:
        [a: T[I], b: X<U[I]>]
    }]): void;
```

And this also works:

```
foo2([
    ['a', `do something here with a`], // okay
    ['b', `do something here with b`], // okay
    ['c', `do something here with c`], // okay
    // ...
    ['x', "do something here with w"], // error!
    ['y', "do nothing"], // error! 
    ['z', "do something here with z"] // okay
])
```

It's possible that someday (soon?) there will be an official `NoInfer<T>` type and then you can just use it.  Until then you can use one of these alternatives.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAITDAlolBvYFIlAFwE85UANAHgBUUoAPEqEAExhRhICcsQAcwB8KALwoABuwD23GdBIALAYJRKovVAHcsylABI8dAL6TghYuyiIANmC0oAZgFcQiElhkhnMmQCZ6RhY2ThQtMFkQWzJuPlUAbQBdYQAKS2JiEhc4W1gALnCoSO8YlASAOiq8coBJFAEUAGsoMhknFDok-IzMvoSwQroE2qSAGhQAI0LaYdHhJN7MkySASkKANxksdgBuC16nP39UhKXiBIByMEuJ6TkYBShlVXVNHT0lFDBJcfOiK6TW5SWTyRQqIRvRy6fSTX5jf7lS6IYH3MHPCFqDTQz4oRDwxEAekJKCqFURVyYwIARKDHuDXtiPvptNTxihiSgQHJNLwZLwAPwAQgplzINNB3JeQjZE05vP5Ir6F0uAC8JQ8ntKse8UDCvqq2b01r1OUcAjQEtSwNSJtTJraUNTEI7qUxqSgAD5O1l2siuw0pVKAe6JVsATBZwNB4EhUABRT6afC9ciUFCzYKsDhcHj8ISiCRo+kYxm6-WGYxmCyZax2ByoVzuTzeXwWhjMLNhCJRMq5xLsgCqmdCXDoaUR2VyBSKJWisUq1TqDR8LTaHS6PWVyoGQxG7Om6ZoA73C0RK3WKC2O321eI5pOZy3SJudzpWsxUOZXx+fyfgNRb4MpCTJ6ricK-luVwoq+mpATqOL6PiEHKpyZKilSdqASWwFlrirLsvKvB8rwSqQWKGpcjI2qyhyJIKiRorqphsHYfBX4oIGxphuGkaQLACDICgADyvDJpkqbUEEHYjnEeYiOIIIsdqn6gfoRimOY4kUKgAByMi1CATiaPQBblF0CTtiE2YoG4TTctoPgCigAAMKCFCAUAbJoiw1jY9iOI2HheD495SVZXbFD2sR9kIyTjk+k55DAhTdqU85kjUIzLs0rTtJ03SIpkO6dHuEwHrQekGUZvD0Cep5PuemzbHst5EPepyii+inospIHlj+cokjITRgGQopAjBPUfn1YHwrRKDDaNorQd1xa9bhiFzZyi1jU+qFVOhFFrdNG1fPhg2MERiqiuKzGUdRBF0VdJEoIxR3vqWCEGmy807VxFgmEAA)

Comment: In the solution that uses a second type parameter, IIUC, it works because `U` will not be inferred such that it influences `T`, in fact, it seems that nothing the user inputs will cause `U` to infer? I would like to better understand when and when not does TS infer. Could you explain it a bit more here? How do you know `U` won't succumb to inference?

Comment: I added a little more. I don't want to digress into a full discussion about how to emulate `NoInfer`, or generally how inference works. A sketch:  `U` *will* be inferred from the user input, but it will be *constrained* to `T`, and that's where the failure happens, if they're not compatible.  The only possible worry is that `T extends U` would cause `T` to be inferred from the user input for `U`, but constraints are not used as inference sites, so that means `T` is only inferred from `[a: T[I],` and `U` is only inferred from `b: X<T[I]>]`. And if `U` is not assignable to `T`, you get an error.

Comment: Thanks! I came across another case that I couldn't figure out, this time with objects, if you have time maybe your amazing skills can resolve that one too... : ) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75944857/how-can-this-function-taking-object-of-types-be-typed-in-ts